# Granting cpusets permissions to non-root user

Tags: linux, permissions, cgroups

By default, only `root` can create CPU sets (and manipulate tasks in existing ones):

```
$ cset shield -c0
cset: **> [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/cpusets//user'
cset: insufficient permissions, you probably need to be root
```

If I granted user `trusted` the right to run `sudo cset`, the commands he/she will run, e.g.

```
sudo cset shield -e command
```

would be owned by `root`, unless we do

```
sudo cset shield -e sudo -- -u trusted command
```

which is quite complex, especially regarding what environment is inherited by `command` through these layers...

Is there a way to grant `trusted` rights to manipulate CPU sets without changing identity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [cpuset man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/cpuset.7.html):

> The permissions of a cpuset are determined by the permissions of the
>   directories and pseudo-files in the cpuset filesystem, normally
>   mounted at /dev/cpuset.

Using a small, sudo-callable script, that creates a cpuset and adapts the ownership/permissions of the corresponding folder and files in it, a user would be allowed to create is own cpuset.

Then the user can use and modify this cpuset directly without root permissions and create child cpusets for it.

See also https://serverfault.com/questions/478946/how-can-i-create-and-use-linux-cgroups-as-a-non-root-user .

Comment: Thank you for the answer and for the pointer (I learned that creating a cpuset is as simple as `mkdir`). The `cpuset` pseudo-fs does not support ACLs, so here's what I did: (i) create a trusted-users group (ii) `mount -t cpuset none /cpusets` (this is the default mountpoint for the `cset` utility) (iii) `chown -R :trusted-users /cpusets` (iv) `find /cpusets -perm -u=w -exec chmod g+w '{}' \+`

Comment: The files are actually at `/sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset` (as referenced in the link) but it might depend on the distro.